# react router html5 pushstae with Nginx

Tags: html, nginx, react-router

I have a react app (which uses react-router and html5 pushstate route)
I would like http://example.com/v2 as base route to server my new website

I use these nginx config:

this to catch the /v2 and use the new js files

```
location ^~ /v2 {
        alias /usr/local/theapp/dist;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /v2/index.html;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/theapp/acces.web.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/theapp/error.web.log debug;
}

location ~ ^/(v2)/.+\..+$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
       alias /usr/local/theapp/dist;
       error_log /var/log/nginx/theapp/error.web.log debug;
}
```

Since with the first location block, even a 404 will be be redirect to v2/index.html, so The intention of the second location is to handle the uri with extension,  so if `http://example.com/v2/user/profile/picture.jpg` does not exists, then I will still get the proper 404 resource not found error.

Above code obviously does not work, because ^~ has higher priority then ~. Tried with 2 ~ but I get try_files redirect loop :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you note, the second location block will not be accessed. Also, the `alias` is more complex when used in conjunction with a regular expression location. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) for more.

The use of `alias` and `try_files` together can cause problems (see [this long standing bug](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/97)).

Try:

```
location ^~ /v2 {
    alias /usr/local/theapp/dist;

    if (!-e $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^[^.]*$ /v2/index.html last;
    }

    access_log /var/log/nginx/theapp/acces.web.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/theapp/error.web.log debug;
}
```

See [this note](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) on the use of `if`.

Comment: The problem with your solution is it cannot solve the html5 state push feature. if I go  `example.com/v2/user/profile`  it will not work, because `example.com/v2` is real path, and  `user/profile` is just html5 router. thats why I use `try_files` so everything after `/v2/` fall to v2/index.html

Comment: I misunderstood that you only want a 404 response if the URI contains a `.`. See revised answer.